# Razor page property gets empty on handler call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am using ASP.NET Core and have the following `MyPage.cshtml`:

```
@page
@model MyServer.Pages.MyPageModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MyPage";
}

<h1>MyPage</h1>

@foreach (var sub in Model.Items)
{
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="isSelected" checked="@sub.Value" />
        <label for="isSelected"><strong>@sub.Key</strong></label>
    </div>
}

<a asp-page-handler="Save">Save</a>
```

And the following `MyPage.cshtml.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace MyServer.Pages
{
    public class MyPageModel : PageModel
    {
        public Dictionary<string, bool> Items = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Items.Add("Item 1", true);
            Items.Add("Item 2", false);
            Items.Add("Item 3", false);
            Items.Add("Item 4", false);
            Items.Add("Item 5", true);
        }

        public void OnGetSave()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Save button clicked!!");
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to trigger the `Save()` method when the Save element is clicked. But currently it "clears out" the other data on the page:

[image]

How do I create a button element to trigger a `Save()` method to save the state of my data?

Comment: You don't appear to have a form in your Razor Page. You also need name attributes on your form inputs. You should read some basics about forms in Razor Pages: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms

Comment: @HameedSyed This is not MVC. There are no controllers in Razor Pages: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to trigger the Save() method when the Save element is clicked. But currently it "clears out" the other data on the page

As @MikeBrind mentioned, please put them in a form and specify `name` attribute for your  inputs, like below.

```
<form method="post">
    @foreach (var sub in Model.Items)
    {
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="isSelected" checked="@sub.Value" name="@sub.Key" />
            <label for="isSelected"><strong>@sub.Key</strong></label>
        </div>
    }

    <button asp-page-handler="Save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Then you can access selected items from `Request.Form` collection and use `RedirectToPage` method(s) to redirect to current page or a specified page, like below.

```
public IActionResult OnPostSave()
{
    var fb = Request.Form;

    var selected_items = string.Join(",", fb.Keys.ToList().Take(fb.Keys.Count - 1));

    //code logic to save selected items

    Console.WriteLine("Save button clicked!!");


    return RedirectToPage();
}
```